# Time travel story about a bullied girl who travels to dancehall/ballroom and meets her relative

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm trying to find a story that was either a stand alone novel or a short story in a scary story anthology for young adults.  What I remember from the story is that the girl came from a poor family and was bullied at school (in the beginning of the story she is taunted by a group of boys).

I thinks she wanders along some sort of boardwalk, and ends up in an abandoned ballroom or dancehall, where she travels back in time. She ends up dancing with a man that's her relative (might be her grandfather or her uncle), but gets freaked out for some reason and runs away, only to bump into one of the bullies who is nice to her and walks her home.

There may have been a subplot about the relatives's jacket or coat involved, and I think the main character may have been on the boardwalk contemplating suicide. It would have likely been from the late 90s or early 00s, and definitely published before 2010.